# Does write-ahead logging in Android have any impact?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my database-heavy Android application, we enabled write-ahead logging on capable devices (honeycomb+) hoping to see reads occur in parallel and our performance boosted. Debugging through traceview has shown that we are not getting the parallel reads we hoped for. I did some debugging by enabling verbose logging on the SQLiteDatabase:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteDatabase VERBOSE
```

Indeed, we see that the max connection pool size is fixed at 1:

```
I/SQLiteDatabase(11051): db: /data/data/mobisocial.musubi/databases/MUSUBI.db, totalsize = 1, #free = 1, maxpoolsize = 1
I/SQLiteDatabase(11051): , conn # 1, mCountHolders = 0, freeBusyFlag = true
```

Has anyone had any luck getting parallel reads working in the Android database?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your connection string to control the `maxpoolsize` value.

```
Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=10;
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip, but I don't think the connection string is something I can specify when connecting Android to its sqlite database. I'll search around, though.

Comment: @bjdodson - If you call `DriverManager.getConnection`, try pasting this to the end of the first parameter.